# Automatically create valid links

Tags: python, url

I'm new to python, so please bear with me :)

I was wondering if there's any built-in way in python to append variables to URL's regardless of it's structure.

I would like to have a URL variable (test=1) added to an URL which could have any of the following structures

> http://www.aaa.com (would simply add
>   "/?test=1") to the end
>
> http://www.aaa.com/home (like the one
>   above, would simply add "/?test=1") to
>   the end
>
> http://www.aaa.com/?location=home
>   (would figure out there's already a ?
>   being used, and would add &test=1 to
>   the end)
>
> http://www.aaa.com/?location=home&page=1
>   (like the one above, would figure out
>   there's already a ? being used, and
>   would add &test=1 to the end)

I'd be happy to write domething to do it myself, but if python can already do it somehow, I'd me more than happy to use any built-in functionality that would save me some time ;-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using both [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587627/automatically-create-valid-links/4587774#4587774)'s and [Adam Vendenberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587627/automatically-create-valid-links/4587657#4587657)'s suggestions, you could do something like this:

```
import urllib
import urlparse

query=urllib.urlencode({"test":1})
urls=['http://www.aaa.com',
      'http://www.aaa.com/home',
      'http://www.aaa.com/?location=home',
      'http://www.aaa.com/?location=home&page=1']
for url in urls:
    x=urlparse.urlparse(url)
    new_query=(x.query+'&'+query) if x.query else query
    y=urlparse.urlunparse((x.scheme,x.netloc,x.path,x.params,new_query,x.fragment))
    print(y)
```

yields

```
http://www.aaa.com?test=1
http://www.aaa.com/home?test=1
http://www.aaa.com/?location=home&test=1
http://www.aaa.com/?location=home&page=1&test=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like urllib.urlencode: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: Any examples you could give me??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the urlparse library (called urllib.parse in Python 3) can help you do this:

http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

Specifically the urlparse and urlunparse methods.